# MySQL proxies_priv ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode

Tags: mysql, mariadb, docker

I'm running MySQL (MariaDB) inside docker container and with every start, it shows the following warning:

> [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@mariadb-3702996102-qbr18' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

So, it writes the current container hostname in `proxies_priv` and since I have option `skip-name-resolve` in my.cnf it gives the warning.

Is there a way to hide this warning? Perhaps there's an option to not write the hostname variant to `proxies_priv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is useful because it tells you that this proxy privileges will never be matched.

Your options are:

- you delete this privilege
- you change the `@` part to `%` or to a defined ip address
- you disable `skip-name-resolve` (which will slow down MySQL, which will now depend on the DNS resolver speed: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html)

### Update

Just tested MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 5.7, and it seems that even if the warning appears, `localhost` is replaced by `127.0.0.1` with `--skip-name-resolve`. A bug was opened: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81441

Clearly MySQL should only warn if the domain isn't localhost, as with a disabled resolver the rule won't apply at all, only `@your.ip.address.number` and `@localhost` would work.

Comment: It seems this was enough for the OP, but I'm stumped.  How can I fix this, or is it something that should just be ignored?

Comment: @Codemonkey I really think you can ignore it. Test it with http://mysqltuner.pl that's the best way to find out about security and performance issues.

Comment: Yeah it's that that complained about it, but only in a non-specific nature about warnings in my startup log file

Comment: First I don't understand why it creates this privilege with the container name and second I don't understand where to change the part @ in the configuration.
That's the problem, I can't figure out how to apply the correct settings.

Comment: @jcarlosweb best way to edit this setting is to use phpmyadmin or MySQL WorkBench. If it's just a warning with no consequences (see the bug report I mentioned), just ignore it.

Comment: I have solved it this way https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/164#issuecomment-916786263, but it is not quite clear to me as I say in the thread.